# Dropbox API, Python3, Requests 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, dropbox-api

I am able to authenticate and connect to the DropBox API and run [`team-members-list`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team-members-list).

But I get the following error when I attempt to run [`team-members-remove`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team-members-remove) with additional header and data in the request.

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:

When adding `try`:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Python code so far:

```py
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN}
url = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team/members/remove'
data = {
    "user": {".tag": "team_member_id", "team_member_id": userid}, 
    "wipe_data": "true", 
    "transfer_dest_id": {".tag": "team_member_id", "team_member_id": adminid},
    "transfer_admin_id": {".tag": "team_member_id", "team_member_id": adminid},
    "keep_account": "false",
}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I have attempted some variations on the above, including:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN, "Content-Type": "application/json" }
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
data = json.dump(data)
```

There are a few of these errors documented here, I've had a read of them and implemented the suggestions but still not been able to resolve this.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Background:

- Python 3.5.2
- Requests
- Dropbox for Business API

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for formatting.  Looks much better.  Will submit this way going forward.

Comment: No problem. Can't help you with the question itself though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I was going wrong was I was attempting to run the response.text through json.loads e.g.

```
message = json.loads(response.text)
```

I changed this to

```
print(response.text)
```

This way I was presented with the helpful error messages.

Code now looks like this and its working:

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
jsondata = json.dumps(data)
response = requests.post(url, data=jsondata, headers=headers)
```